# Return the list content contained in the given cell

Tags: excel

I have data like below. I would like to fill Column2 with a value in list column(E) if one of that value is substring of Column1.
I am able to assert that condition and return TRUE or FALSE , but not return the actual string in List column.
Any help?
[image]

Update:
I referred [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things) to return TRUE or FALSE based on the condition

Comment: Please add your formula.

Comment: can we see the formula that "return TRUE or FALSE" ? ( :

Comment: Added as an update to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it combining SUMPRODUCT with INDEX.

I got this:

[image]

My formula in E1 and dragged down is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$4;SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$4;A6));ROW($E$1:$E$4)));"Not found")
```

This is how it works:

1. Part `SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$4;A6));ROW($E$1:$E$4)))` will return an array of 1 and 0 if the text is found/not found. And we multiply those 1 and 0 by the row number of each option in the list. If nothing is found, it will return 0
2. With `INDEX` and the number returned in step 1, we just list the element.
3. We trap `INDEX` with `IFERROR` because sometimes step 1 will return 0, raising error on step 2 if nothing is found, so we return text "not found".

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

**IMPORTANT:** This formula will work if there is 0 or 1 coincidences. If there are more, the formula won't work, because it will return a sum of 2 or more row numbers, and then INDEX will raise an error. Watch out for that

Example: if you type GRAY DOG, the formula will return 5 (coincidences at row 1 and 4, and summed up). But with INDEX you are looking in a range of only 4 rows, not 5, so it will raise an error.